# how to make an array of errors inside of a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, constructor

I want the constructor validate $contraseña and $rcontraseña to see if they match.
If they do: Hash the password.
If they dont: Create an array of errors where $errors[password] contains a string that says "Passwords dont match".

My problem with the the following code is:

var_dump($errores); is not showing the string, probably because the way I am trying to fill it is wrong. The array is outside the class, I also tried to make it as a public, private and protected attribute, but none of these worked either.

```
<?php
// Array de errores. Si todo está null es porque no hubo errores.
  $errores = [
  "nombre" => "",
  "apellido" => "",
  "usuario" => "",
  "contraseña" => "",
];

class Usuario {
  /* atributos */
  protected $nombre;
  protected $apellido;
  protected $usuario;
  protected $contraseña;

  /* Métodos. */
  /* Constructor que setea datos, los verifica y hashea contraseña. */
  public function __construct($nombre, $apellido, $usuario, $contraseña, $rcontraseña){
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
    if ($rcontraseña == $contraseña) {
      $this->contraseña = password_hash($contraseña, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
    else {
      $errores['contraseña'] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden.";
    }
    // Verificamos que nombre no esté vacío.



  }


}


$emiliano = new Usuario("Emiliano", "Vargas", "emicapo", "emi123", "eemi123");

var_dump($errores);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of having this construct

```
$emiliano = new Usuario("Emiliano", "Vargas", "emicapo", "emi123", "eemi123");
```

is so you can use `$emiliano` and, say, `$fernando` as two different Usuarios. Having a single global `$errores` defeats the purpose.

You should be able to write:

```
var_dump($emiliano->errores());
```

and have the errors *pertaining to that user only*.

To do this you have to declare the errors inside the class, and since you do not need to access them from outside directly (the function errores() does that for you), you will declare them **private**:

```
class Usuario {
     /* atributos */
     protected $nombre;
     protected $apellido;
     protected $usuario;
     protected $contraseña;

     /* errores, default empty. */
     private $miErrores = [ ];
```

Inside the class you need the errors returning

```
     public function errores() {
         return $this->miErrores;
     }

     public function hayError() {
         return count($this->miErrores);
     }

     protected function nuevoErrore($errore, $texto) {
         $this->miErrores[$errore] = $texto;
         return $this;
     }

     // You might need to remove errors without destroying the object
     protected function borrarErrores() {
         $this->miErrores = [ ];
         return $this;
     }
```

Then you add an error like this:

```
    $this->nuevoErrore('contraseña', 'Las contraseñas no coinciden.');
```

You can check quickly for errors with,

```
    if ($emiliano->hayError()) {
         var_dump($emiliano->errores());
         die();
    }
```